# Is there a setting to echo 0 in php?

Tags: php

I understand that 0 is considered an empty string. But one of my hosts has no problem displaying it as 0 while the other displays it as blank, what can I change in the latter host to make it display 0 and not just a blank?

possibly an option in the php.ini file?

example:

```
<?php 

$sum = 0.0; 
echo $sum; 

?>
```

the code above will display 0 in the first host and nothing in the second host.

the only thing that works is by doing this

```
echo " " . $sum
```

but that will cause incompatibility with the other host.

Comment: show your code where you want to echo this 0.

Comment: Does it output to cli or to html?

Comment: @Mustafa Taleb you are trying to assign 0.0 in $sum which actually assign 0 try to assign 12.0 it will display only 12.

Comment: @RedTaz I tried using strval, casting to string and other formatting methods and they all returned blank on the second host, but 0 on the first. Here is the same exact file on the [first host](http://localdisksolutions.com/test.php) and on the [second host](http://chainlotto.com/test.php)

Comment: @SatishSharma I don't think that the 0 after the decimal is relevant. I've tried testing with and without and I got the same exact results.

Comment: Do you mind checking the PHP versions on both machines?

Comment: @Alexander PHP Version 5.3.26 on the first and PHP Version 5.3.13 on the second. I can link to the phpinfo files of both if you think it would help.

Comment: @MustafaTaleb, according to [this](http://3v4l.org/gSLK6), those versions should output `0`. Hope you can find the reason why it is not

Answer (score 1):

If you cast the variable to a float `echo` should interpret it as a number, instead of (I suspect) the boolean value `FALSE`.

```
<?php 

$sum = 0.0; 
echo (float)$sum; 

?>
```